# Is it possible to use Entity Framework Core with ODBC?

Tags: entity-framework-core, odbc

My company's main software application hasn't been updated in twenty years. I expect to soon be working on a complete rewrite of it. To that end, I am beginning to work my way through the book "Pro ASP.Net Core 3" by Adam Freeman (8th edition).

Our application was written to be independent of specific database types. Most of our customers use PostgreSQL, but a few use SQL Server. Therefore, we use ODBC because ODBC drivers exist for both of those databases, as well as several others. The application does not do anything fancy with the databases, and ODBC works well. We configure an ODBC DSN to talk to whichever database the customer has, and the application itself doesn't have to be changed.

A search on "Entity Framework Core ODBC" led me to the EF Core Github, where people have asked similar questions, and the answers were mostly along the lines of "why on earth would you want to do that?". Well, I need to do that.

Can I use EF Core with ODBC, or is there some other way that I can set up an Entity Framework Core application that does not have to be modified if the underlying database changes from PostgreSQL to SQL Server?

Comment: Answer is the same - don't even do that. Writing own ODBC provider for EF Core takes about several months without bug fixing. You really want to participate in that gambling? Current SQLServer and PostgreSQL providers are faster than ODBC. And yes you can switch between SQLServer and PostgreSQL if there is no provider specific mappings and types.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  No, I definitely don't want to bother with writing my own ODBC provider.  Would I need separate builds for SQL Server and PostgreSQL databases, or is there a way to use EF Core to create a program that will work with either one, depending only on a connection string in the applicaton.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your appsettings.json to store a value used to swap between the two. Those environment configs get reloaded on change (though you might have to restart your application to read them again, I'm not sure on that one).

Regardless something along the lines of this would suit your needs I think.

```
if (Configuration.GetSection("dbOptions")["postgres"]))
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgresConnectionString")));
  else
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServerConnectionString")));
```

EDIT: I placed this in Startup.cs where you would normally configure the DBContext. I use a similar solution reading off the Environment type to load either the Prod or QA connection strings based on deployment. In principle, this should accomplish the same task without the need for rebuilding and redeploying the code base.

Comment: Thank you.  I think this will serve my needs.  I only hope I'll remember it when we actually get around to updating this application.